# Rotate a BufferedImage around its center point

Tags: java, rotation, bufferedimage, graphics2d

So, I'm making a game in java swing (personal choice, don't turn this into a X is better to make games in, thanks), a 2d platformer.

I'm trying to rotate my weapon, using this code:

```java
BufferedImage weapon = invArmor.getWeapon().getItem().getTexture();

AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();

tx.setToRotation(Math.toRadians(weaponRotation), weapon.getWidth() / 2, weapon.getHeight() / 2);

AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
weapon = op.filter(weapon, null);

if (facingRight)
    g.drawImage(weapon, posX() + 10, posY() + 5, 24, 24, null);
else
    g.drawImage(weapon, posX() + 10, posY() + 5, -24, 24, null);
```

The problem is this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FWXsc5Z.gifv]

The image turns around as if it was bound to the size of the image itself! diagonals are compressed horizontal and vertical, and it gives a bouncy effect. Not what i'm looking for...

I want it to rotate around it center point, so nothing is being compressed!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are explicitly "compressing" the image, by specifying a fixed width and height to `drawImage(img, x, y, height, width, observer)`.

The rotation itself works as it should. But note that when rotating an image, the bounds will increase, otherwise the image would be clipped.

So, instead of:

```java
if (facingRight)
    g.drawImage(weapon, posX() + 10, posY() + 5, 24, 24, null);
else
    g.drawImage(weapon, posX() + 10, posY() + 5, -24, 24, null);
```

Simply do:

```java
g.drawImage(weapon, posX() + 10, posY() + 5, null);
```

If facing right, simply flip the image (`weapon`) by adding a flip operation (you can scale by -width as you did in `drawImage`) to your affine transform (`tx`) before rotation.

You might need to recalculate the x/y position relative to the rotated image's new bounds, but that should be trivial. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help ! that worked too, but I need to scale the image down though. Luckily I roamed the interwebs some more, and found a good solution.

Comment: `AffineTransformOp` is pretty good at scaling too, so you could just add scaling and do it all in one go.. :-) There's no information in the question about the need to scale down, and the scaling you did really was the reason the original code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a blank canvas image to draw the image onto worked as it should.
I hope this code can help someone in the futur

```java
BufferedImage weapon = invArmor.getWeapon().getItem().getTexture();

int size = 32 + 20;

//create blank canvas that is bigger the the image drawn.
BufferedImage canvas = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
//get grapchics from the canvas
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) canvas.getGraphics();

//rotate canvas internally
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(weaponRotation), size / 2, size / 2);

//draw image centered, extra/2
g2d.drawImage(weapon, 10, 10, null);

if (facingRight)
    g.drawImage(canvas, posX() + 5, posY() - 15, size, size, null);
else
    g.drawImage(canvas, posX() + 19, posY() - 15, -size, size, null);
```